# When I switch from GameScene to a new scene I get a gray screen and my code doesn't run

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scene

For some reason when I try to switch from my GameScene to a second scene, the screen turns gray, but none of my code that is written in my second scene is executed. I think the issue may have to do with what is written in the GameViewController, because when I switch the code below from let scene = GameScene() to let scene = EndScene, the code in EndScene runs fine. There has to be a simple issue I'm somehow overlooking. If I need to supply more information please let me know, I'm fairly new to spritekit.

I currently have this code:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scene = GameScene()
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
        scene.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
        scene.size = skView.bounds.size 
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
        } else {
            return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

The code that I'm using to switch from my GameScene to the EndScene is:

```
self.view?.presentScene(SKScene(fileNamed:"EndScene."))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SKScene constructor is looking for a file named EndScene, when it's actually a class. Try making a function similar to viewDidLoad in the GameViewController class:

```
func toEndScene() {
    let skView = self.view as! SKView
    let eScene = EndScene()
    eScene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
    eScene.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    eScene.size = skView.bounds.size 
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

I would assume that this works considering that switching out GameScene for EndScene in the viewDidLoad worked for you.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I replaced my old code with that new code in my GameScene and my app immediately crashed.

Comment: Please try again with this updated code. If it's still crashing, could you paste in the beginning of the crash?

Comment: I ended up just copy and pasting my code to a new project and it worked. I might have accidentally removed some code from the first project. Thanks for the help.